# Here's my code. I am trying to get user input of integers, go through a function utilizing map and returning a list of cubed results

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, user-input, map-function

I am using Python 3

```
vals = int(input("Enter comma separated numbers"))

def cube(nums):
    return nums**3

print(list(map(cube,vals)))
```

I get this error when I input 2,3

```
#Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/administrator/Documents/Python/Master Python/Day7a.py", line 15, in <module>
    vals = int(input("Enter comma separated numbers"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,3'
```

This works when I put the integers myself, though:

```
vals = [2,3]
def cube(nums):
    return nums**3

alist = (list(map(cube,vals)))
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and show a full example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convert the input from the user to a sequence of integers (or floats, if so desired) before you can map `vals` to perform numeric operations:

```
vals = map(int, input("Enter comma separated numbers").split(','))
```